# How to link dynamically loaded unbounded subforms to main form?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, recordset, subform

I have a bound main form (FormA) with a combobox on it and two unbound subforms (subfrmA & subfrmB). (Both forms are attached to a table however I want them to load onto the main form where I placed an unbound subform as a placeholder.)

The combobox has two values “a” and “b.” When a is selected I want subfrm A to load onto Form A. When b is selected I want subfrmB to load onto Form A. I think have this part working.

However when I select a record on the main form the associated subforms don’t appear. When I try to link the subforms to the main form an error message appears saying I can’t build a link between unbound forms.

The packageID is the link between the main form and subform and is a hidden field on all forms. Whenever the packageID is automatically updated the psckageID in the subform fields are also updated.

[image: form design view]

```vb
Case”A”                  
    Me.subfrmAB.SourceObject=“FormA
    Me.packageDetailsID=Me.subfrmAB.packageDetailsID
Case “B”                                                  
    Me.subfrmAB.SourceObject=“FormB”
    Me.packageDetailsID=Me.subfrmAB.packageDetailsID
```

EDIT: I ended up creating two subforms subfrmA (Form A) and subfrmB (Form B). Then I linked both to the parent form via the master and child links.

I make one of the subforms visible and the other invisible depending on what the user selects in the combobox of the main form.

Everything works except Form B won’t load, but the container loads. I tried loading Form B separately by itself it still won’t load. I also deleted subfrmA and Form B still doesn’t load.

Here is my edited code:

```vb
Select Case Me.Authorization.Text
    Case “A”
        Me.subfrmA.Visible = True
        Me.subfrmB.Visible = False
        Me.subfrmA.SourceObject = “Form.A”
    Case “B”
        Me.subfrmB.Visible = True
        Me.subfrmA.Visible = False
        Me.subfrmB.SourceObject = “Form.B”
End Select
```

The only line that doesn’t work is the `Me.subfrmB.SourceObject=“Form.B”` and really there’s something that’s preventing the form specifically loading. I wrote the same code for Form A and Form B but can’t figure out what’s wrong with Form B.

Comment: An unbound subform has no record to show until filled with _one_ record, not several. I guess you need to rephrase your question or reconsider your setup.

Comment: I’m new to access and vba. Is there a way to do the below. 

I’d like to dynamically load a specific subform onto the main form based on combobox selection from the main form. 

And when user clicks on a specific record within the main for, I’d like the associated subform to appear.

Comment: What do you mean by 'unbound' subform? If form has a RecordSource it is bound. Set subform container control properties: SourceObject, MasterLink, ChildLink. Edit question to post attempted code. What tables are forms bound to?

Comment: @June7 Thank you. I added pictures and a little more description.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you. I added a bit more to my question maybe this clears up the issue I have

Comment: Code should be posted as text, not image. Why would you need to black out object names? Why are you setting PackageDetail_ID value? That makes no sense. Are all forms bound to data - have RecordSource?

Comment: @June7 Sorry, I added the code as a txt with nothing blacked out. 

The reason I set the packageDetailID value is because I want the subform packageDetailID to auto populate based on the main subform. 

All forms are bound to data.

Comment: @June7 

subfrmAB is the name of the unbound subform placeholder on the main form. So really I have three forms. I want the main form to generate the correct form based on the value selected in combobox on main form. Then when I search a record in the main form, the correct associated form should appear

Comment: You don't populate a form by setting one of its field values. That will not pull existing records, it only puts value into a field. You need to either set RecordSource property with a filtered dataset by reference to a query object or use an SQL statement. Or apply filter by setting Filter and FilterOn properties of form that has static RecordSource. How did you get smart quote characters in your code - VBA will not like those. And your code shows syntactical errors. Did you not copy/paste?

Comment: @June7 So all my forms have a RecordSource and I’m pretty sure it’s a static RecordSource. I copied the code from another stackoverflow source. And it seems to be working so far. What does the filter do? Thank you

Comment: If they all have RecordSource then what do you mean by "unbound subforms"? Why use code to set value of packageDetailsID? This either starts a new record or changes value of existing. Why do you have two subforms - are they using same data source? Instead of two forms possibly just need to apply filter. If all is working, what is your issue?

Comment: @June7 I mean “unbound subform” because the subform placeholder where I want the forms to populate based on user selection is unbound. 
So if user selects A then form A is populated in the subform placeholder and the same for value B. 

The packageDetailsID is the primary key for the main form RecordSet. It is linked to the packageDetailsID on the subforms. The reason I use code to set the packageDetailsID is because whenever someone creates a new record I want the the subform packageDetails field to automatically update. And I don’t know how else to do it

Comment: @June7 I have two subforms that do not use the same source data. I want the form to populate a different data source based on the combobox selection on main form. 

My issue is: The step where the correct subform populates depending on user selection in combobox works. However when I click on a record in main the associated subform doesn't pop up

Comment: Subforms don't 'pop up', subforms are placed within a subform container on a main form. If Master/Child links are set properly, subform should only display records related to main form record. It is not necessary to programmatically set value of packageDetailsID of subform. This will automatically populate when user begins data entry in any other control on subform, assuming Master/Child links are correct.

Comment: How do you 'select' record on main form - post code. Is combobox UNBOUND? Controls used to input selection criteria should be UNBOUND. Code appears to be setting value of control on main form = to field on subform - that is very odd. What event is code in? Problems like this benefit from direct analysis of db but since SO does not allow attaching files, SO appears not to be appropriate forum.

Comment: @June7  the combobox is bound, it is tied to a record set, I want whatever the user enters in combobox to populate in the actual table. It is also the criteria for loading the subform. 

So the subform container in this case is the unbound subform on the main form where I want the subforms to load. This is wha I link using master and child links.

When I say select record, I mean whenever I navigate or scroll to a specific form I want the associated subform to load.

Comment: @june Is there a way to dynamically load subforms based on user input on the main form, and have the subforms linked to the main form using master and child links.

Comment: It is unclear what form names are. You say FormA is main form and subforms are subfrmA and subfrmB yet code shows setting subform container to FormA and FormB.

Comment: @June7 I made a lot of edits got everything to work except one line, can you please take a look?? Thank you!

Comment: Why is your code posting with smart quotes instead of normal quotes? If I were to copy/paste your code into VBA, it would error because of those quotes. Why do form names have a dot? Object names should not use spaces nor punctuation/special characters. Doubt I could determine cause of issue without examining db.

Comment: @June7 hmmm that’s weird, I typed up the code on my table, my actual code uses regular quotes. Also I figured out my issue, the an expression in my query wasn’t working so the subform itself wouldn’t load.

Comment: Was answer instrumental in resolving issue? If so, please mark accepted.

Comment: @June7 your answer was extremely helpful! I have accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can certainly be done. Here is a simple example that works for me.

Main form is bound to table Games. Forms used as subform are Umpires and Teams.

Combobox properties:

> ControlSource: UNBOUND
> RowSource: Umpires;Plate;UmpID;Teams;HomeTeam;TeamID
> RowSourceType: ValueList
> BoundColumn: 1
> ColumnCount: 3
> ColumnWidths: 1.0";0";0"

Code:

```
Private Sub Combo108_AfterUpdate()
With Me
.ctrAB.SourceObject = .Combo108
.ctrAB.LinkMasterFields = .Combo108.Column(1)
.ctrAB.LinkChildFields = .Combo108.Column(2)
End With
End Sub
```

You could have "A", "B" for the form names in combobox RowSource and then if both forms have same name key fields, don't need them in RowSource, just hard coded. Not entirely clear what the key field names are. Then code like:

```
.subfrmAB.SourceObject = "subfrm" & .Combo108
.subfrmAB.LinkMasterFields ="packageDetailsID"
.subfrmAB.LinkChildFields = "packageDetailsID"
```

If you want to save "A" and "B" to main form record, then bind the combobox to field. Then for subforms to change for each record while navigating main form, also have code in form OnCurrent event.

Something to be aware of when coding interaction between form/subform: subforms load before main form - seems odd but is true.

Comment: sorry it’s FormAB, subfrmA and subfrmB. Thank you so much, I will try

Comment: what is “plate” and “home team” under row source? Is .ctrAB the name of the subform or subform control? 

So put the above code within the OnCurrent event of the combobox button? 

Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Plate and HomeTeam are foreign key fields in Games saving ID values. ctrAB is subform container control. Code in combobox AfterUpdate and form OnCurrent events.

Comment: The relationship is between a data table and two lookup tables. Maybe not the best choice for demonstration but it works (not an implemented form/subform arrangement in my db, just for test). Your relationship is probably between a table and dependent tables such as Packages and PackageDetails in which case the key fields will likely be reverse of mine. Something like: MasterLink will be PackagesID and ChildLink would be PackagesID_FK.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a dummy table with one record and bind the subform to that. But you'd have to read and write all the values with code.